# How to use grep to search for options in a man page?

Tags: command-line, grep, manpage

I want to search for specific options like `-s`, `-f`, `-l` in a manpage and display only the results that contain info on what those options do. I tried this command hoping that the single quotes would bypass `grep` from receiving options:

```
man --pager=cat some_man_page_here | grep '-option_here'
```

I also tried `\` but `grep` gives me a syntax error:

```
Usage: grep [OPTION]... PATTERNS [FILE]...
Try 'grep --help' for more information.
```

I just wanna know if there's a way to use `grep` to search for options in manpages. I'm currently using the *Find* button on the terminal top bar but I'd like to be able to use `grep` for efficiency.

Comment: You don't need `grep` at all. Just type / followed by the string to search for.

Comment: I wrote an answer in the thread, linked to in the close box, to treat multiple options at once.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Would this work in your case?

```
$ man ls | grep -- '--a'
     -a, --all
     -A, --almost-all
     --author
```

A more detailed (hopefully clearer) example of the command:

```
$ man shutdown | grep -- '-'
       shutdown - Halt, power-off or reboot the machine
       shutdown may be used to halt, power-off or reboot the machine.
       logged-in users before going down.
       --help
       -H, --halt
       -P, --poweroff
           Power-off the machine (the default).
       -r, --reboot
       -h
           Equivalent to --poweroff, unless --halt is specified.
       -k
           Do not halt, power-off, reboot, just write wall message.
       --no-wall
           Do not send wall message before halt, power-off, reboot.
       -c
       On success, 0 is returned, a non-zero failure code otherwise.
```

Edit:

As [glenn jackman commented below](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1281432/how-to-use-grep-to-search-for-options-in-a-man-page#comment2174454_1281435) (very useful):

> And to narrow down the results to just lines starting with a hyphen:
>
> ```
> grep '^[[:space:]]*-' –
> ```

Test run:

```
$ man shutdown | grep -- '-' | grep '^[[:space:]]*-'
       --help
       -H, --halt
       -P, --poweroff
       -r, --reboot
       -h
       -k
```

One could obviously also use **apropos** in Linux.

[+] External Links:

[Full-text search for man pages - At Unix SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/8982/full-text-search-for-man-pages)

Comment: And to narrow down the results to just lines starting with a hyphen: `grep '^[[:space:]]*-'`

Comment: Oh thank you this worked for me!

Comment: @glennjackman That's impressive! thanks for saying that!  Edited my answer to include your comment //Regards

Comment: +1 Maybe would be useful to explain why OP's command doesn't work.

Answer (score 5):

working with a simple function to return only the specific part related to the command's switches and their followed short-description in addition, from their man-pages directly:

```
sman() {
    man "${1}" \
    | grep -iozP -- "(?s)\n+\s+\K\Q${2}\E.*?\n*(?=\n+\s+-)"
}
```

Call it **`sman <command-name> <switch>`** like: `sman ls -A`

```
-a, --all
              do not ignore entries starting with .
 -A, --almost-all
              do not list implied . and ..
```

Explanations (from https://regex101.com/):

---

- `-i` — enable case-insensitive match
- `-o` — return only matched part
- `-z` — Treat input and output data as sequences of lines, each terminated by a  zero  byte  (the  ASCII  NUL character) instead of a newline.
- `-P` — enables PCRE

---

- `(?s)` match the remainder of the pattern with the following effective flags: **s**
  ***<sup>s modifier</sup>*** — single line. Dot matches newline characters
- `\n+` matches a line-feed (newline) character
  ***<sup>+ Quantifier</sup>*** — Matches between *one* and *unlimited* times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (*greedy*)
- `\s+` matches any whitespace character
- `\K` resets the starting point of the reported match. Any previously consumed characters are no longer included in the final match
- `\Q${2}\E` Quoted Literals — matches the expanded *$2* characters literally
- `.*?` matches any character
  ***<sup>*? Quantifier</sup>*** — Matches between *zero* and *unlimited* times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (*lazy*)
- `\n*` matches a line-feed (newline) character
  ***<sup>* Quantifier</sup>*** — Matches between *zero* and *unlimited* times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (*greedy*)
- `(?=\n+\s+-)` Positive Lookahead: Assert that the Regex below matches:
  `\n+` matches a line-feed (newline) character.
  `\s+` matches any whitespace character
  `-` matches the character `-` literally.